# Did anything change about keep offset?

Tags: rigging

I'm learning about rigging these days and got a little issue about
keep offset

so the video says I need to press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>    +  <kbd>P</kbd>   after selecting 2 parent-child  armature

unfortunately, this didn't work as intended.

I even searched on edit mode> armature> parent> make

it did NOT have keep offset

ofc, I found keep offset by simply joining two armatures

but in the video, no <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> was used

he simply pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to use keep offset.

I'll leave the link of the video I watched

thanks

link: https://youtu.be/cUC3W_rW7dc